# Ionic Angular - Nested ion-router-outlet rendering as page instead of sub-component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using a nested ion-router-outlet in order to render routes as a subcomponent, rather than take the entire page.

This is my current route configuration:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
  { 
    path: 'dashboard', 
    component: Dashboard,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'submit', loadChildren: './submission/submission.module#SubmissionModule' }
    ]
  }
];
```

My current dashboard template in the dashboard component:

```
<!-- dashboard.html-->
<h2 id="dashboard-header">Dashboard</h2>
<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

When go I to `/dashboard/submit` the submission component takes up the entire page, covering the dashboard heading. Looking into the styling for the ion-router-outlet and submission component I see the following
:

```
.ion-page {
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;
position: absolute;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
contain: layout size style;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
}
```

How can I remove this styling for ion-router-outlet? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, your submit page is loading as sub-component.

[image: angury lazy loading example]

You have to work on layout. Angular router logic is working fine.

Try to add this code inside your dashboard.html and you can understand how component and sub-component work:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="6">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>DASHBOAD COMPONENT</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="6">
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```